# How do I check whether given files have dependency bugs?

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, adjacency-list

I'm fairly new to C++ and have been given the following assignment:

Given that I have the set of the following files: alpha.cpp, bravo.cpp and charlie.cpp, I'm supposed to create a program that checks whether those files have a dependency bug.

My thoughts are to have the program read the files, create an adjacency list graph, having each file as a vertex and directed edges going from one node to another should one .cpp file include another .cpp file. So overall, I would need to run a depth first search on the graph to see if the graph has any back edges.

Would that be the right track? I feel like I understand what I should do, but I'm not sure how to implement it exactly.

Comment: What's a dependency bug?

Comment: @immibis It's when there's a cyclic dependency among files. So let's say alpha.cpp uses charlie.cpp and charlie.cpp uses alpha,cpp. A dependency bug exists since you need to compile one before you compile the other

Comment: Create a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), and [Check for Cycles](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/).

Comment: @immibis A dependency bug can also be when -- one include file depends on another include file being included. This happens quite a bit when you're using a language that allows globals -- 4GL -- and one program needs only several items from one global definitions file, so you have to include that even though you only need a few definitions from that file. The other answer you got from trugnt relates more to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use your build system with a little bit of parsing magic.  I've got a Makefile that I use for a lot of projects [here](https://bitbucket.org/smcallis/makegold/src/19d338e61be6df3c4b5798e54ab32e3549fa7568/Makefile?fileviewer=file-view-default).  It parse out the includes and generates targets for them.

The thing about tools like Make is they have to do a graph traversal for you.  They do this by taking all your partial orderings (dependency declarations), and doing a topological sort on it to get a complete ordering (linearization of the files so that if A depends on B, B is before A).

But, the thing about a topological sort is that it only exists for a direct *acyclic* graph.  So, if you generate your dependencies like that Makefile, and there's any cycles, the build will fail, which is what you want because it would happen anyways when you try to recursively include things.

Comment: I'm thinking about creating a DAG per Elliot Frisch's suggestion in the comments. The trouble I'm having is how do I get c++ to read each file to find that alpha.cpp, for example, is dependent on bravo.cpp? Would I just have it look for #include 'bravo.cpp'?

Comment: So, generally the .cpp files won't actually be dependent on each other, usually it's headers that are.  If you want to do it in C++, you have to parse the files like you said and look for the #include statements.  I'd use a regular expression library (probably PCRE) to grab those out.  You can build your graph as an adjacency list, and then topologically sort that.  You're welcome to steal the regex from that Makefile I linked to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and suggestions. This has been very helpful! I'm not actually sure if my instructor wants us to use a makefile to help with the task, however. I think this all must be done with my main.cpp. Basically I need to input the files and  the output should read: "The files can be complied in the order charlie --> bravo --> alpha."

Comment: Ah I see this is a school project.  If you're limited to just the files that are input, then you can probably parse the files using just fscanf and build the graph that way, otherwise a regex library for C++ is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside: The definition on a "dependency bug" per the comments in your question isn't very useful. Generally speaking, `a.h` including `b.h` including `a.h` doesn't have to be a bug of any sort. If the files that include them compile, then obviously you have valid C++. So, not a bug. The following scenarios arise:

1. A given dependency cycle might be unnecessary: some `b.h` might not really need to include `a.h`. Compilation succeeds.
2. A given dependency cycle might be necessary, but valid: some `b.h` might need contents from `a.h`, and it might provide something back to `a.h`, but the include statements and dependencies are ordered such that it works. Compilation succeeds.
3. A given dependency cycle might be necessary, and invalid: it's impossible to satisfy the dependencies as stated. Compilation fails.

To detect #3, you only need to compile the file, if the compilation fails, you might have a dependency bug.

There might be a possible reordering of the declarations/definitions in `a.h` and `b.h`, and of the include statements, that converts #3 to #2.

The #2 and #1 aren't necessarily bugs, but you'll have to completely parse the files to determine that these are the case.

Of course you can simply *declare* these cycles to be not allowed in your project. So they are against your project rules, and perhaps that lets you call them bugs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for tools to see the dependencies, I'd consider using:

- `makedepend` or `g++ -MD` (or `clang++ -MD`) for generating `#include`-dependencies. Then build a graph to detect loops.
- `g++ -c` and `nm` (`-U` and `--defined-only`) to read which symbols are defined and required in object files. You can even just compare the list of defined and declared symbols (including the symbols defined somewhere like `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`) to see if there are missing symbols at all.